# how to install mangal.ttf on linux (centos)

Tags: linux, centos, fonts, truetype-fonts

I've downloaded mangal.ttf from `cghs.nic.in/hindiFont.jsp` and copied it to `/usr/share/fonts/TTF` ; somehow the system is not able to recognize it (I'm verifying same using LaTeX). Is there any documentation for installing fonts on Linux ?

Answer (score 9):

You can see the documentation [here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-x-fonts.html).

1. To add fonts system-wide, copy the new fonts into the `/usr/share/fonts/` directory. 
   It is a
   good idea to create a new subdirectory, such as local/ or similar, to help distinguish between user-installed and default fonts.

   To add fonts for an individual user, copy the new fonts into the `.fonts/` directory in the user's *home directory*.
2. Use the `fc-cache` command to update the font information cache, as in the following example:

> `fc-cache <path-to-font-directory>`

In this command, replace `<path-to-font-directory>` with the directory containing the new fonts (either `/usr/share/fonts/local/` or `/home/<user>/.fonts/`).